# `chrome.scripting.getRegisteredContentScripts` always returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I have a Chrome extension with an action that I'm using to test `getRegisteredContentScripts`. The action boils down to:

```js
const result = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId },
    injectImmediately: true,
    files: [
        "js/contentScript.bundle.js"
    ]
})
console.log(result);
const scripts = await browser.scripting.getRegisteredContentScripts();
console.log(scripts);
```

This logs:

```
[{"documentId":"79E2F787C5E2EFB02BAD520D660A6606","frameId":0,"result":null}]
[]
```

So in other words it seems to be injecting the script, and indeed I can see the content script running in my browser, but `getRegisteredContentScripts()` always returns an empty array.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: executeScript doesn't register scripts, it only injects on demand, so it won't be listed in getRegisteredContentScripts. To register scripts you can use registerContentScripts, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/).

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting point. Can you distinguish why one might want  `executeScript()` as opposed to `registerContentScripts`? I would then accept this as an answer